# I need to get a maya file from Turbosquid to blender

Tags: blend-files, conversion

I’ve tried finding online converters from .ma to .blend but none of them worked. The only thing that I’ve found that might work is an addon for blender that’s $28, but I don’t want to spend any money.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way that I know of. .ma is a proprietary format just like .blend is a proprietary format. You would be better using a generic 3D format like .fbx, or .obj to bring the file into Blender. Many Turbosquid models have multiple formats already available to download. If yours doesn't, you might try Turbosquid's conversion option: https://www.turbosquid.com/Conversion/Index.cfm